# Copy Hbase table to another with different queue for map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I run CopyTable action on Hbase

```
hbase -Dhbase.client.scanner.caching=100000 -Dmapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --new.name=desc src
```

but map reduce is spowned on the default queue. How to run this task on different Application Queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=$queue ...
```

Comment: Also, we have to put the queue name in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
-Dmapred.job.queue.name=<the-queue-you-want>
```

into the command.

Comment: Nope, still on default.